# Python: Count the occurence of a number being smaller than a threshold accross row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with a MultIndex like this:

```
df.index.levels
FrozenList([[u'params', u'pvals', u'statistics', u'std'], [u'x1', u'x2', u'x3', u'x4', u'Hx5', u'adj_r2', u'r2', u'_f_test']])
```

You can guess that `df` contains an OLS output. Is there a `pandas` function that I can use to count how many times a number in the index `pvals` for each `x1 x2 ... x5` is less than 0.05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df.ix["pvals"].ix[["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"]] < 0.05).sum()
```

The trick is here that Python converts `True` to 1 and `False` to 0 when you use them in an arithmetic context.

Comment: wait there is a typo. It should be `(df.ix["pvals"].ix[["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"]] < 0.05).sum()`

Comment: Also, in this case it has to be `sum(axis=1)` IIRC. When testing I used columns named `"x1" …`.